# Finding a cycle of fixed length

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, co.combinatorics

Is there any result about the time complexity of finding a cycle of fixed length $k$ in a general graph?
All I know is that [Alon, Yuster and Zwick](http://www.tau.ac.il/~nogaa/PDFS/col5.pdf) use a technique called "color-coding",
which has a running time of $O(M(n))$, where $n$ is the number of vertices of the input graph and $M(n)$ is the time required to multiply two $n \times n$
matrices.

Is there any better result?

Comment: I suppose your n is the number of nodes in the graph.

Comment: Yes, it is. Thanks for the supplement.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Finding a cycle of any *even* length can be found in $O(n^2)$ time, which is less than any known bound on $O(M(n))$. For example, a cycle of length four can be found in $O(n^2)$ time via the following simple procedure:

> Assume the vertex set is $\{1,...,n\}$. Prepare an $n$ x $n$ matrix $A$ which is initially all zeroes. For all vertices $i$ and all pairs of vertices $j, k$ which are neighbors to $i$, check $A[j,k]$ for a $1$. If it has a $1$, output *four-cycle*, otherwise set $A[j,k]$ to be $1$. When this loop finishes, output *no four-cycle*.

The above algorithm runs in at most $O(n^2)$ time, since for every triple $i,j,k$ we either flip a $0$ to $1$ in $A$, or we stop. (We assume the graph is in adjacency list representation, so it is easy to select pairs of neighbors of a vertex.)

The general case is treated by Raphy Yuster and Uri Zwick in the paper:

> Raphael Yuster, Uri Zwick: Finding Even Cycles Even Faster. SIAM J. Discrete Math. 10(2): 209-222 (1997)

As for finding cycles of odd length, it's just as David Eppstein says: nothing better is known than $O(M(n))$, including the case where $k=3$.

However, if you wished to detect *paths* of length $k$ instead of cycles, you can indeed get $O(m+n)$ time, where $m$ is the number of edges. I am not sure if the original color-coding paper can provide this time bound, but I do know that the following paper by some random self-citing nerd gets it:

> Ryan Williams: Finding paths of length k in O*(2^k) time. Inf. Process. Lett. 109(6): 315-318 (2009)

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the result about detecting paths.
It's new to me and it is very useful. Thanks!!

Comment: A linear time algorithm (i.e., O(m+n)) for detecting paths of length k  was mentioned in one of Alon et al.'s papers. It just involves choosing a random ordering of the vertices, and making the graph a DAG using this ordering. Since longest path on DAGs can be solved in linear time, a directed path of length k can be found in linear time, if the chosen random ordering works. Repeat the previous step exponentially many times (in k), to get desired randomized algorithm.

Comment: Rune is absolutely right; the random ordering algorithm runs in O(k! (m + n)) time.

Comment: Good stuff. How can I detect _every_ cycle of length 4 though? The algorithms you reference seem to only tell you if such a cycle exists or not.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. There can be $\Omega(n^4)$ cycles of length 4 in a graph, so $O(n^4)$ time is the best you can hope for asymptotically if you want to list all 4-cycles. If you're asking how to get the above algorithm to produce a 4-cycle in $O(n^2)$ time when one exists, that's also pretty obvious...

Comment: At first I wondered why you insulted Ryan Williams...

Answer (score 9):

If there's a deterministic or randomized algorithm with better dependence on $n$ than $M(n)$ even for the first nontrivial case, $k=3$ (that is, testing whether the given graph contains a triangle) then I don't know about it. Nothing better is listed on [the Wikipedia article on triangle-free graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle-free_graph), for instance. There do exist quantum algorithms for finding 3-cycles that are faster, however: see [arXiv:quant-ph/0310134](http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0310134).

It's also possible to find bounds that are better than $M(n)$ for graphs that are not dense (number of edges sufficiently smaller than quadratic). For instance even fairly naive algorithms can find triangles in time $O(m^{3/2})$ where $m$ is the number of edges in the graph.

Comment: Thanks for the useful information. I also noticed that for planar graph you gave a linear time algorithm for detecting any bounded size graph. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 6):

If we restrict to the class of planar graphs, then there is a linear time algorithm due to [Eppstein](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=313830).  It is also linear for graphs of bounded tree-width since the problem of finding a cycle of fixed length can easily be encoded as a monadic second-order logic formula, and we can then appeal to Courcelle's theorem.

**Edit.** The related problem of finding a cycle of length $a$ (mod $k$) has not been proven to be polynomial (except in the case $a=0$).

Comment: A polynomial bound for general graphs (for any fixed k) is given by the Alon et al color-coding paper that the original question cites.

Comment: Finding a cycle of length being a multiple of k is a pretty interesting question. Thanks for the information!

Comment: If we consider graphs with edges labelled from a finite abelian group, then we can define the *group-value* of a cycle as the sum of its edge labels.  For a fixed element g of the group, we can then ask if there is cycle with group-value g.  Cycles of length 0 (mod k) are a special instance of this problem, where the group is $Z_k$, g=0, and all edge labels are 1.  

Answer (score 2):

Basically everyone above hit the nail on its head. I want to add an algorithm of counting every cycles of length 4 in an undirected graph, which runs in $O(n^3)$ instead of $O(n^4)$

Every cycle of length four includes four nodes $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$. Thus for every pair of nodes, $u$ and $v$, you count the number of nodes that are neighbors to both $u$ and $v$. Then the problem of counting every cycle of length four transforms to the problem of selecting 2 such nodes that are adjacent to both $u$ and $v$.