# Finding a 5-cycle in a sparse graph efficiently.

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity, matrices

Hi,

I was reading this thread: [Finding a cycle of fixed length](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16393/finding-a-cycle-of-fixed-length)

I want to find a 5-cycle in a graph.  Actually, what I *really* want is a shortest odd cycle of length at least 5, but maybe that is a little beside the point.  For my purposes, I treat $m$ and $n$ the same in the complexity analysis.

Can we do better than colour coding for finding a 5-cycle in this case?  Let me give a specific formulation of my question:

> What is the minimum $\alpha$ such that there is an $O(m^\alpha)$-time algorithm for detecting a cycle of length 5?  What is the algorithm?  And what is this $\alpha$ if you forbid impractical methods like Coppersmith-Winograd fast matrix multiplication?

Answer (score 1):

This paper talks about short cycle detection.

http://people.clarkson.edu/~ebollt/Papers/LComm.pdf

If it doesn't completely answer your question perhaps it can serve as a bound or as a starting point for further literature search.