# Finding a cycle of a specific length in an edge-weighted graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms

I'm looking for some suggestions on how we might calculate cycles of a specific length in an edge-weighted graph.

For example, imagine my phone tells me that I need to walk three miles today. It might be nice if the phone could calculate a few tours of appropriate length, ideally avoiding things like walking up and down the same streets repeatedly.

A [previous posting](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16393/finding-a-cycle-of-fixed-length) reviewed some algorithms for finding fixed-length cycles in unweighted graphs. However, I'm not aware of anything concerning the edge-weighted case.

A simple algorithm for a road network might work as follows. Assume that I want a cycle of length $x$ that starts and ends at a source vertex $s$. Now use Dijkstra's algorithm to produce a shortest path tree. Next, find the node $v$ in this tree whose distance from $s$ is close to $x/2$. Our solution then involves walking from $s$ to $v$ and then back to $s$ again. While this algorithm is polynomial, the solution is not great as we will end up walking up and down the same streets (so its not really a cycle at all...).

Another option might be to convert a weighted graph into an unweighted one. Assuming all edge-weights are integer, an edge of length $x$ is replaced by a chain of $x-1$ vertices, as the following demonstrates:

[How to convert an edge weighted graph into an unweighted graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21xL0.jpg)

We can then apply methods used for the unweighted graphs. An issue with this approach is that it could massively increase the size of the graph. Given that [existing approaches](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16393/finding-a-cycle-of-fixed-length) for simple graphs can be quite expensive, this doesn't seem like a good idea.

Does anyone have any ideas/thoughts?

Comment: if your cycles must not re-visit vertices, then it's a hard problem, as hard as TSP.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik If you just do not want to revisit edges, there is a trivial realization of the knapsack problem in the given setup: just consider the graph with 2 vertices and multiple edges of lengths $0,w_1,\dots,w_n$ between them. Then just ask if you can make a path of length exactly $W$. However, as the setup suggests, we do not really need to achieve exactly $W$: a multiplicative factor close to $1$ should be allowed, in which case knapsack is just polynomial, so there is some hope. Of course, the minimal length computation is a red herring if we want just to stroll, not to get anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

To help answer my own question, here's a paper that I recently published on this topic. Thanks also for the suggestions of Manfred Weis above.

Lewis, R. and P. Corcoran (2022) 'Finding Fixed-Length Circuits and Cycles in Undirected Edge-Weighted Graphs: An Application with Street Networks'. *Journal of Heuristics*, vol. 28, pp. 259-285.

https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s10732-022-09493-5.pdf

Answer (score 0):

There are the so-called diverse routing algorithms that manage to calclulate the edge-disjoint or vertex-disjoint pair of paths with minimal lengths-sum between a pair of  vertices. With such an algorithm you can check all pairs of points and filter out the ones, that have path-sum that comes close enough to the desired cycle length.